# SAPUI5 - Update Association / Foreign Key to another Category for a Product

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have a simple requirement to update 'category Id' for a given product **'from SAPUI5 client application'**.

My database design for product and category is:
**Category** table has ID, Name and Description.
**Product** table has ID, Name, Description and category_id. Category_id is a foreign key to Category table and is a required column in this table.

Implemented OData service with CRUD operations. These operations are tested using postman with json input requests. An example create (POST) request:

> {
>       "Name": "iPads 18the Dec",
>       "Description": "iPad 2019 18th Dec",
>       "Category@odata.bind": 1 }

a PATCH request: (for update)

> {
>       "Description": "Notebook Basic, 1.7GHz - 15 XGA - 1024MB DDR2 SDRAM - 40GB - updated",
>       "Category@odata.bind": 2 }

I am using SAPUI5 sap.m.Table to display Products. The table's list binding sends automatic requests in case of any change in the record (item). During this process it sends only Product information without category id.

This is troubling me when I want to change the category id. Say, my table list binding is “{/Products}”. 
If I use the binding “{Category/ID}” for category id, it is sending update request on Category entity.

My request should be something like this:

> { "name": "name 1", "Category@odata.bind": 2 }

How can we achieve this in SAPUI5?

Below is the important code.

**View.xml**

```
   <mvc:View
    controllerName="sap.ui.core.tutorial.odatav4.controller.ProductsController"
    displayBlock="true"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
    <VBox>
        <items>
            <Table
                id="productsTable"
                growing="true"
                growingThreshold="3"
                items="{
                        path: '/Products',
                        parameters: {
                            $count: true,
                            'expand': 'Category'
                        }, 
                        events:{
                            change: '.onChangeHandler'
                        }
                    }"
                mode="SingleSelectLeft">
                <!--  ,$$updateGroupId : 'peopleGroup' -->
            <headerToolbar>
                <OverflowToolbar>
                    <content>
                        <ToolbarSpacer/>
                        <SearchField
                            id="searchField"
                            width="20%"
                            placeholder="{i18n>searchFieldPlaceholder}"
                            enabled="{= !${appView>/hasUIChanges}}"
                            search=".onSearch"/>
                        <Button
                            id="addUserButton"
                            icon="sap-icon://add"
                            tooltip="{i18n>createButtonText}"
                            press=".onCreate">
                            <layoutData>
                                <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="NeverOverflow"/>
                            </layoutData>
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                            id="deleteUserButton"
                            icon="sap-icon://delete"
                            tooltip="{i18n>deleteButtonText}"
                            press=".onDelete">
                            <layoutData>
                                <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="NeverOverflow"/>
                            </layoutData>
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                            id="refreshUsersButton"
                            icon="sap-icon://refresh"
                            enabled="{= !${appView>/hasUIChanges}}"
                            tooltip="{i18n>refreshButtonText}"
                            press=".onRefresh"/>
                        <Button
                            id="sortUsersButton"
                            icon="sap-icon://sort"
                            enabled="{= !${appView>/hasUIChanges}}"
                            tooltip="{i18n>sortButtonText}"
                            press=".onSort"/>
                    </content>
                </OverflowToolbar>
            </headerToolbar>
            <columns>
                <Column id="userNameColumn">
                    <Text text="{i18n>userNameLabelText}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column id="firstNameColumn">
                    <Text text="{i18n>firstNameLabelText}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column id="lastNameColumn">
                    <Text text="{i18n>lastNameLabelText}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column id="tierIdColumn">
                    <Text text="{i18n>tierIdLabelText}"/>
                </Column>
                <!-- <Column id="tierIdColumn2">
                    <Text text="Category Id placeholder" />
                </Column> -->
            </columns>
            <items>
                <ColumnListItem id="table_col">
                    <cells>
                        <Input
                            value="{ID}"
                            valueLiveUpdate="true"
                            liveChange=".onInputChange"/>
                    </cells>
                    <cells>
                        <Input
                            value="{Name}"
                            liveChange=".onInputChange"/>
                    </cells>
                    <cells>
                        <Input
                            value="{Description}"
                            liveChange=".onInputChange"/>
                    </cells>
                    <cells>
                        <Input value="{Category/ID}" liveChange=".onInputChange"/>
                    </cells>
                </ColumnListItem>
            </items>
        </Table>
                <!-- <footer> -->
                    <Toolbar visible="{appView>/hasUIChanges}">
                        <ToolbarSpacer/>
                        <Button
                            id="saveButton"
                            type="Emphasized"
                            text="{i18n>saveButtonText}"
                            enabled="{= ${message>/}.length === 0 &amp;&amp; ${appView>/usernameEmpty} === false }"
                            press=".onSave"/>
                        <Button
                            id="doneButton"
                            text="{i18n>cancelButtonText}"
                            press=".onResetChanges"/>
                    </Toolbar>
                <!-- </footer> -->
            </items>
    </VBox>
</mvc:View>
```

**Controller.js**

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/m/MessageToast",
    "sap/m/MessageBox",
    "sap/ui/model/Sorter",
    "sap/ui/model/Filter",
    "sap/ui/model/FilterOperator",
    "sap/ui/model/FilterType",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "sap/base/Log"
], function (Controller, MessageToast, MessageBox, Sorter, Filter, FilterOperator, FilterType, JSONModel, Log) {
    "use strict";

    var CATEGORIES_TABLE_ID = "productsTable";

    return Controller.extend("sap.ui.core.tutorial.odatav4.controller.ProductsController", {
        /**
         *  Hook for initializing the controller
         */
        onInit : function () {
            var oMessageManager = sap.ui.getCore().getMessageManager(),
                oMessageModel = oMessageManager.getMessageModel(),
                oMessageModelBinding = oMessageModel.bindList("/", undefined, [],
                    new Filter("technical", FilterOperator.EQ, true)),
                oViewModel = new JSONModel({
                    busy : false,
                    hasUIChanges : false,
                    usernameEmpty : true,
                    order : 0
                });
            this.getView().setModel(oViewModel, "appView");
            this.getView().setModel(oMessageModel, "message_layers");

            oMessageModelBinding.attachChange(this.onMessageBindingChange, this);
            this._bTechnicalErrors = false;

            // Can I attach an event listener to include category_id before submit
        },


        /* =========================================================== */
        /*           begin: event handlers                             */
        /* =========================================================== */

        onChangeHandler: function(oEvent){
            var eventName = oEvent.getParameter("reason");
            console.log("Change: Event raised: " + eventName + ", timestamp = " + new Date().getTime());

        },

        /**
         * Create a new entry.
         */
        onCreate : function () {
            var oList = this.byId( CATEGORIES_TABLE_ID );
            var oBinding = oList.getBinding("items"),
                // Create a new entry through the table's list binding
                oContext = oBinding.create({
                    "ID" : null,
                    "Name" : "",
                    "Description" : "",
                    "Category@odata.bind": 1
                });

            this._setUIChanges(true);
            this.getView().getModel("appView").setProperty("/usernameEmpty", true);

            // Select and focus the table row that contains the newly created entry
            oList.getItems().some(function (oItem) {
                if (oItem.getBindingContext() === oContext) {
                    oItem.focus();
                    oItem.setSelected(true);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        },

        /**
         * Delete an entry.
         */
        onDelete : function () {
            var oSelected = this.byId( CATEGORIES_TABLE_ID ).getSelectedItem();

            if (oSelected) {
                oSelected.getBindingContext().delete("$direct").then(function () {
                    MessageToast.show(this._getText("deletionSuccessMessage"));
                }.bind(this), function (oError) {
                    MessageBox.error(oError.message);
                });
            }
        },

        /**
         * Lock UI when changing data in the input controls
         * @param {sap.ui.base.Event} oEvt - Event data
         */
        onInputChange : function (oEvt) {
            if (oEvt.getParameter("escPressed")) {
                this._setUIChanges();
            } else {
                this._setUIChanges(true);
                // Check if the id in the changed table row is empty and set the appView property accordingly
                if (oEvt.getSource().getParent().getBindingContext().getProperty("ID")) {
                    this.getView().getModel("appView").setProperty("/usernameEmpty", false);
                }
            }
        },

        /**
         * Refresh the data.
         */
        onRefresh : function () {
            var oBinding = this.byId( CATEGORIES_TABLE_ID ).getBinding("items");

            if (oBinding.hasPendingChanges()) {
                MessageBox.error(this._getText("refreshNotPossibleMessage"));
                return;
            }
            oBinding.refresh();
            MessageToast.show(this._getText("refreshSuccessMessage"));
        },

        /**
         * Reset any unsaved changes.
         */
        onResetChanges : function () {
            this.byId( CATEGORIES_TABLE_ID ).getBinding("items").resetChanges();
            this._bTechnicalErrors = false; // If there were technical errors, cancelling changes resets them.
            this._setUIChanges(false);
        },

        /**
         * Reset the data source.
         */
        onResetDataSource : function () {
            var oModel = this.getView().getModel(),
                oOperation = oModel.bindContext("/ResetDataSource(...)");

            oOperation.execute().then(function () {
                    oModel.refresh();
                    MessageToast.show(this._getText("sourceResetSuccessMessage"));
                }.bind(this), function (oError) {
                    MessageBox.error(oError.message);
                }
            );
        },

        /**
         * Save changes to the source.
         */
        onSave : function () {
            var fnSuccess = function () {
                this._setBusy(false);
                MessageToast.show(this._getText("changesSentMessage"));
                this._setUIChanges(false);
            }.bind(this);

            var fnError = function (oError) {
                this._setBusy(false);
                this._setUIChanges(false);
                MessageBox.error(oError.message);
            }.bind(this);

            this._setBusy(true); // Lock UI until submitBatch is resolved.
            this.getView().getModel().submitBatch("peopleGroup").then(fnSuccess, fnError);
            this._bTechnicalErrors = false; // If there were technical errors, a new save resets them.
        },

        /**
         * Search for the term in the search field.
         */
        onSearch : function () {
            var oView = this.getView(),
                sValue = oView.byId("searchField").getValue(),
                oFilter = new Filter("description", FilterOperator.Contains, sValue);

            oView.byId( CATEGORIES_TABLE_ID ).getBinding("items").filter(oFilter, FilterType.Application);
        },

        /**
         * Sort the table according to the Description.
         * Cycles between the three sorting states "none", "ascending" and "descending"
         */
        onSort : function () {
            var oView = this.getView(),
                aStates = [undefined, "asc", "desc"],
                aStateTextIds = ["sortNone", "sortAscending", "sortDescending"],
                sMessage,
                iOrder = oView.getModel("appView").getProperty("/order");

            // Cycle between the states
            iOrder = (iOrder + 1) % aStates.length;
            var sOrder = aStates[iOrder];

            oView.getModel("appView").setProperty("/order", iOrder);
            oView.byId( CATEGORIES_TABLE_ID ).getBinding("items").sort(sOrder && new Sorter("description", sOrder === "desc"));

            sMessage = this._getText("sortMessage", [this._getText(aStateTextIds[iOrder])]);
            MessageToast.show(sMessage);
        },

        onMessageBindingChange : function (oEvent) {
            var aContexts = oEvent.getSource().getContexts(),
                aMessages,
                bMessageOpen = false;

            if (bMessageOpen || !aContexts.length) {
                return;
            }

            // Extract and remove the technical messages
            aMessages = aContexts.map(function (oContext) {
                return oContext.getObject();
            });
            sap.ui.getCore().getMessageManager().removeMessages(aMessages);

            this._setUIChanges(true);
            this._bTechnicalErrors = true;
            MessageBox.error(aMessages[0].message, {
                id : "serviceErrorMessageBox",
                onClose : function () {
                    bMessageOpen = false;
                }
            });

            bMessageOpen = true;
        },

        fnFormatter: function(text, key) {
            var sText = "";

            if (text && key) {
                sText += (text + " (" + key + ")");
            } else if (text) {
                sText += text;
            } else if (key) {
                sText += key;
            }

            return sText;
        },


        /* =========================================================== */
        /*           end: event handlers                               */
        /* =========================================================== */


        /**
         * Convenience method for retrieving a translatable text.
         * @param {string} sTextId - the ID of the text to be retrieved.
         * @param {Array} [aArgs] - optional array of texts for placeholders.
         * @returns {string} the text belonging to the given ID.
         */
        _getText : function (sTextId, aArgs) {
            return this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText(sTextId, aArgs);
        },

        /**
         * Set hasUIChanges flag in View Model
         * @param {boolean} [bHasUIChanges] - set or clear hasUIChanges
         * if bHasUIChanges is not set, the hasPendingChanges-function of the OdataV4 model determines the result
         */
        _setUIChanges : function (bHasUIChanges) {
            if (this._bTechnicalErrors) {
                // If there is currently a technical error, then force 'true'.
                bHasUIChanges = true;
            } else if (bHasUIChanges === undefined) {
                bHasUIChanges = this.getView().getModel().hasPendingChanges();
            }
            var oModel = this.getView().getModel("appView");
            oModel.setProperty("/hasUIChanges", bHasUIChanges);
        },

        /**
         * Set busy flag in View Model
         * @param {boolean} bIsBusy - set or clear busy
         */
        _setBusy : function (bIsBusy) {
            var oModel = this.getView().getModel("appView");
            oModel.setProperty("/busy", bIsBusy);
        }

        ,onSelect: function(oEvt){
            var selectedCategoryId = oEvt.getSource().getSelectedKey();
            this.byId("category_id_4_product").setValue( selectedCategoryId );
        },
        /**
         * Copies category_id value from placeholder column to actual column
         */
        _copyToInputField: function( oCells, value ){
            for( var i=0; i < oCells.length; i++ ){
                if( oCells[i].getId().match( "category_id_actual" ) ){
                    oCells[i].setValue( value );
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "_version": "1.12.0",
    "sap.app": {
        "id": "sap.ui.core.tutorial.odatav4",
        "type": "application",
        "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
        "applicationVersion": {
            "version": "1.0.0"
        },
        "title": "{{appTitle}}",
        "description": "{{appDescription}}",
        "dataSources": {
            "default": {
                "uri": "/DemoService/DemoService.svc/",
                "type": "OData",
                "settings": {
                    "odataVersion": "4.0"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sap.ui": {
        "technology": "UI5",
        "deviceTypes": {
            "desktop": true,
            "tablet": true,
            "phone": true
        }
    },
    "sap.ui5": {
        "rootView": {
            "viewName": "sap.ui.core.tutorial.odatav4.view.App",
            "type": "XML",
            "async": true,
            "id": "appView"
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "minUI5Version": "1.48.0",
            "libs": {
                "sap.m": {},
                "sap.ui.core": {},
                "sap.ui.layout": {}
            }
        },
        "contentDensities": {
            "compact": true,
            "cozy": true
        },
        "handleValidation": true,
        "models": {
            "i18n": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
                "settings": {
                    "bundleName": "sap.ui.core.tutorial.odatav4.i18n.i18n"
                }
            },
            "": {
                "dataSource": "default",
                "settings": {
                    "autoExpandSelect": true,
                    "operationMode": "Server",
                    "groupId": "$direct",
                    "synchronizationMode": "None"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it not supported in SAPUI5 or is it a peculiar requirement?